# Helping understanding this ring descrption

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following description:

> Consider a ring (R,+,.) with identity 1 that contains two non-identity elements a≠b that satisfy $a^2$ =
>   a and $b^2$ = b. Suppose that every x in R satisfies the equation $x^3$ = x.

I am not quite sure what this means, but here is my attempt at understanding it:

The three elements $(1, a$ and $ b)$ in the ring are real numbers such $b^2$ = b and $a^2$ =
a and they also satisfy $x^3$ = x, so $b^3$ = $b^2b$ =$b^2=b$ , $a^3$ = $a^2a$ =$a^2=a$ and $1^3=1$

Then for instance, if I was to try to show a commutativity axiom of the ring then, which of the following would be correct?

$a+b=b+a$, would be true as the real numbers are commutative

or

$(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3=a+6ab+b=(b+a)^3$, would be true as the real numbers are commutative. But then where does the $x^3$ = x part come in? I used it for when I simplified using $b^3=b$ , $a^3=a$ but shouldn't $(a+b)^3=a+b = b+a=(b+a)^3$ with the same rule?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...or maybe you mixed words. That means what it means: there are two non-identity idempotent elements (and one is zero, by the way...), and it is also **given** that every element $\;x\in R\;$ fulfills $\;x^3=x\;$ ...so then what? What isn't clear here?

Comment: Why do you suppose the idempotent elements in $\;R\;$ are *real number* ??

Comment: Addition is always commutative in a ring. By definition a ring is an abelian (additive) group to which we add a multiplication with a unit that is associative and distributive wrt the addition

Comment: "would be true as the real numbers are commutative" No, it would be true because in any ring we require addition to be commutative.

Comment: You are told that the ring contains $1,a,b$ but there could be more elements as well.  You are also told that every element satisfies $x^3=x$.  Presumably now there is a question coming about the ring.  You don't have to prove commutativity, you are given that because it is a ring. You also cannot assume the elements are real numbers, you can only use the ring axioms plus the added information you have been given.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am not sure what to make of the information x^3=x , when already given the information that the ring has two non identity idempotent elements. For the next steps in the problem I need to prove the ring axioms, so I was unsure what to do with x^3=x

Comment: @glockm15 I've no idea what can possibly be done with that info, perhaps to infere the ring is commutative...but you haven't yet written down what the question is *at all*, so I don't think anyone can tell much about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ here does not refer to the real numbers, it is just what we are naming this particular ring of three elements. (The real numbers are a completely different ring, with *a lot more than three elements*, and where the addition and multiplication properties will work quite differently. If you're working in an arbitrary ring, the elements in that ring will never be "real numbers", unless the ring you're working in is *the* ring of real numbers.)

You don't "show" the commutativity of the elements in this ring, you are already told that it's a ring, so you already know that addition is commutative! That's an axiom of it being a ring. You don't "show" the axioms.

Here's an analogy to something you might be more familiar with to understand how this whole $x^3 = x$ thing works. I'm going to assume you've probably seen some modular arithmetic before: suppose I have the integers mod 3, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$. It contains three elements, which we might like to call, $0$, $1$, and $2$. We know that addition and multiplication in this space work quite differently to how addition works over the integers $0$, $1$, and $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, the result of adding or multiplying any two numbers can be understood by means of the following Cayley tables:

[image: Cayley Table of third finite field[1]]

You know that in this space, we find all kinds of equations like $1+2 = 0$, and $2+2=1$ that clearly do not resemble arithmetic in the real numbers. That's because these numbers certainly aren't from the real numbers -- they just "look similar" out of convention.

Now, if we're in this space of the integers mod 3, you can think about what happens when we multiply things. Consider that clearly $2\times 2 = 1$ (again, see the Cayley table above), and so $2^3 = 2$. We also have $1^3 = 1$ and $0^3 = 0$. So we've shown that $x^3=x$ holds for every element! As it happens, this ring of integers mod 3 is isomorphic to the one you described -- they're the same ring!

It turns out that there only exists one possible ring (up to isomorphism) of three elements, and it's just this relatively familiar space $\mathbb{Z}_3$ that you're probably already familiar with! I hope this clears things up.